# How do parentheses affect code in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, this, parentheses

```js
var obj, method;

obj = {
  go: function() { console.log(this); }
};

(method = obj.go)()
```

NOTE: Fyodor's first comment to his answer is what helped me the most. As the topic suggests, this was more about the parentheses than `this`.

In the last line, what I understand is that the parentheses will force the code inside to run first, so `method` takes the value of the `go` property, which is a function.

The `()` then calls that function, which logs `window` to the console because it wasn't called as a method.

If instead of `(method = obj.go)()`, you do `method = obj.go()`, it will first run the `go` function, and `method` will take the value returned by it. Since `go` returns nothing, it will be `undefined`. The value printed by `go` will be `obj`.

What I don't understand is, why if I do `(obj.go)()` the `this` printed is `obj` and not `window`?

Considering how the other code works, I expected this code to work kind of like this:
`obj.go` is evaluated first inside the parentheses and then the function is run as an IIFE `(function() { console.log(this); })()`. So since the function isn't called as a method of `obj`, the `this` defaults to `window`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`(method = obj.go)()` evaluated in two steps.

1. `method = obj.go` is evaluated and `method` var become equal to function `go` of object `obj`. Functions in JavaScript can be called as methods or as functions, so in general it doen't metter how you;ve defined function `go`.
2. Then `method()` is called. As you didn't provided value for `this` (either by calling `method` function as method of some object or using `bind` or `call` it is called with `this` set to global object (in non strict mode) or to `undefined` (in strict mode)

When you call `obj.go()` `this` is set equal to `obj` (it is similar to use `obj.go.call(obj)` or `method.call(obj)`). If you call just `method()` `this` is equal to global object (similar to call `obj.go.call(window)`)

EDIT

And to get `obj` as `this` with your example you can do such way

```
(method = obj.go.bind(obj))()
```

In this way you not only assign `go` function to variable `method` but create binding to specific `this` equal to `obj`

Good reading about [function invocation and this in JavaScript](https://yehudakatz.com/2011/08/10/understanding-javascript-function-invocation-and-this/)

Comment: I understand all of this. I understand why `this` is what it is in all of the cases you mentioned. What I don't understand is why is `(obj.go)()` the same as `obj.go()`, but `(method = obj.go)()` is not the same as `method = obj.go()`. Why are the parentheses ignored in `(obj.go)()`?

Comment: Parentheses like in many other languages control order of code execution. So for `(obj.go)()` internals of parentheses is evaluated first. It evaluated to `obj.go` as inside parentheses there is nothing to evaluate. Then `obj.go()` is called. When `(method = obj.go)()` is used  there is `method = obj.go` inside parenthese, so here is something to evaluate. After evaluation `method` becomes equal to `go` method of `obj` and on second step just `method()` is called

Comment: It is simply down to the relative precedence of . () and =

Comment: Thank you @Fyodor. I understand now. If I could mark this particular comment as the answer I would, since it's what clarifies my specific doubt. So I'll just mark the whole thing.